# Ant Design with React, menu does not render on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have this app with AntDesign css framework and the sidebar menu does not render into the DOM on mobile view eg. responsive view in developer(after refresh) or on mobile phone. 
On desktop everything works as expected.
What causes the problem?

You can see whole app at: https://github.com/arekrgw/supladevicesinstall

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {Menu, Icon} from 'antd';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import history from '../history'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const SubMenu = Menu.SubMenu

const SideBar = (props) => {
  const currentSlug = history.location.pathname.split('/')[1] || 'welcome'
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(currentSlug)

  const renderMenu = () => {
    return props.menu.map((menuItem) => {
      return <Menu.Item key={menuItem.slug}><Link to={`/${menuItem.slug}`}>{menuItem.title}</Link></Menu.Item>
    })
  }
  return (
    <Menu
      theme="dark"
      onClick={(e) => setCurrent(e.key)}
      selectedKeys={[current]}
      mode="inline"
      defaultOpenKeys={['other']}   
    >
      <SubMenu key="other" title={<span><Icon type="home" /><span>Ogólne</span></span>}>
        <Menu.Item key="welcome"><Link to="/">Home</Link></Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="software">Wstęp (ważne)</Menu.Item>
      </SubMenu>
        {/* Render Menu z API i inteligentne uzywanie slugow */ }
        {renderMenu()}

    </Menu>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  menu: state.menu
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SideBar)
```

```
import React from 'react'
import { Layout } from 'antd'
import SideBar from './SideBar'
import HeaderStyled from './HeaderStyled'
import {Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom'

import FooterDetails from './FooterDetails'
import history from '../history'
import MainContentRoute from './MainContentRoute'

const { Header, Footer, Sider, Content} = Layout

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <Layout>
        <Header style={{borderBottom: '1px solid #0e2549'}}>
          <HeaderStyled />
        </Header>
        <Layout>
          <Sider collapsedWidth={0} breakpoint="md" width="250px">
            <SideBar />
          </Sider>
          <Content>
            <Route path="/:slug" exact component={MainContentRoute}/>
          </Content>
        </Layout>
        <Footer style={{textAlign: 'center', background: "#ddd"}}>
          <FooterDetails />
        </Footer>

      </Layout>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is happening because you're setting a breakpoint for Ant's Sider here:

```
<Sider collapsedWidth={0} breakpoint="md" width="250px">
  <SideBar />
</Sider>
```

I read Ant's docs [here](https://2x.ant.design/components/layout/#components-layout-demo-responsive) and it says following,

> You can get a responsive layout by setting breakpoint, **the Sider will collapse** **to the width of collapsedWidth** when window width is **below the breakpoint**. And a special trigger will appear if the collapsedWidth is set to 0.

Meaning in your case, starting from `992px` and lower, Sider component is collapsed to the collapsedWidth of `0px`.

Comment: Actually I found issue by myself. It was a connect function from react-redux that broke it. Connect function should look like this: 
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null, null,{pure: false})(SideBar)
This issue was discussed here also: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/9867